# Overflow hidden for text in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gridster

I have an element with image and text,

[image]

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/83MJ6/) Note: Resize preview enough to make grid big enough.

Here is my CSS:

```
 .gridster .gs-w .item{

     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

.gridster .gs-w .item .obj{
    background-color: #00A9EC;

 }

.gridster .gs-w .item .itemIcon {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     float:left;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 10;
}  

.gridster .gs-w .item .itemIcon {
    background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/windows-8-metro/256/Apps-Calendar-Metro-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    align-content: center;
} 

.gridster .gs-w .item .itemText{
display: block;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
margin-right: 0px;
right: 0px;
text-align: right;
z-index: 9;
}


.gridster .gs-w .item .itemText a{
vertical-align: center;
text-align:right; 
color:white;
    padding-right: 10%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
```

I want to show text when element is expanded, and hide when element is collapsed, I think I can achieve it by CSS, but it's not yet clear what is wrong.

[image]

and here it is collapsed

[image]

advise some CSS code, in case if possible to make in CSS.

[image: what i need]

Comment: second the need for jsfiddle... or at least some HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/83MJ6/ please user13500 attach this jsfiddle, i couldn't

Comment: why the first five minutes, all active, then no one answers the question, do not even look ...

Comment: No one is answering because your question isn't clear

Comment: look at js fiddle, when element is collapsed. text is visible. but i'm trying to make in hidden

Comment: Do not know gridster. But is there some trigger to detect when item is collapsed? From the looks of it no classes is added, so you can't use a selector based on collapse/expanded. If there is some event on collapsed you could set display to none using JS on that.

Comment: @user2308005, is there something you do when the item is collapsed? Any kind of trigger?

Comment: sincerely I don't know that yet, but i think some CSS proeprties can achive that.. or I'm wrong

Comment: Guess it's impossible, div element height and width are set to percentage, so div cannot use overflow, div will expand for every element inside

Comment: From what I see you can't use only CSS as it is now, as no classes are added or removed on collapse. The only thing that happens on resize is that the CSS properties min-width and min-height is changed. As the gid itself is resized when window is resized you can not use any pre-set positioning either. E.g. by position absolute. But then again – I have not looked too close at it, and there might be a way. Using JS it should be trivial if one can detect collapse in some way.

Comment: it has resize event. http://gridster.net/#resize_start_opt
.resize_widget( **$widget**, **[size_x]**, **[size_y]**, **[reposition]**, **[callback]** )

_Change the size of a widget. Width is limited to the current grid width._
Parameters

**$widget HTMLElement**
**size_x Number**
**size_y Number**
**reposition Boolean**
    

Returns

Returns the jQuery wrapped HTMLElement representing the widget that's been resized.
how can i Use callback

Comment: please don't delete my question. hope someday someone will answer

Comment: @user2308005: Updated answer with fix. From quick tests it looks like it works OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook into [resize.resize](http://gridster.net/#resize_resize_opt).

By checking data attribute `data-sizex` you get how many columns the cell spans. By this you can expand the init function to the following:

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/LgkPJ/)

```
public.init = function (elem) {
    container = elem;
    // Initialize gridster and get API reference.
    gridster = $(SELECTOR, elem).gridster({
        shift_larger_widgets_down: true,
        resize: {
            enabled: true,
            resize: function (e, ui, $widget) {
                var cap = $widget.find('.itemText');
                // Hide itemText if cell-span is 1
                if ($widget.attr('data-sizex') == 1) {
                    cap.hide();
                } else {
                    cap.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }).data('gridster');
    hookWidgetResizer();
}
```

Or cleaner, and likely preferable. Split it out to own function and say something like:

```
resize: capHide
```

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/LgkPJ/1/)

---

If you rather go for the solution proposed by your updated images, one way is to tweak the CSS on resize, using your `resize_widget_dimensions` function. Sure this can be done better, but as a starter you can have this:

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/xRrkT/)

```
this.$widgets.each($.proxy(function (i, widget) {
    var $widget = $(widget);
    var data = serializedGrid[i];
    this.resize_widget($widget, data.size_x, data.size_y);
    // Find itemText
    var $it = $widget.find('.itemText');
    // Set CSS values.
    $it.css({width:this.min_widget_width, left:this.min_widget_width});
}, this));
```

Challenge is that the *gridster* is a very fluid cake where a lot of the dimensions and positioning is done by JavaScript rather then pure CSS. Anyhow, the above should give a direction on how to tweak it, and might even be good enough ;)

---

As a final treat you can resize the font according to cell size. I'm not sure how to best find the size you want as you divide the space between icon/image and text. But something like this:

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/ktePL/)

Where you have a hidden span to measure text:

```
<span id="font_sizer"></span>
```

With CSS:

```
#font_sizer {
    position: absolute;
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And font measure by:

```
function szFont(w, t) {
    var s = 1, $fz = $('#font_sizer');
    $fz.text(t);
    $fz.css('fontSize', s + 'px');
    while ($fz.width() < w - 2)
        $fz.css('fontSize', ++s + 'px');
    return s;
}
```

You can set font size as:

```
var fontSize = szFont(this.min_widget_width - 10, 'Objects');
```

Where `this.min_widget_width - 10` is the part where you set size available for text. Then you can say:

```
var $it = $widget.find('.itemText');
$it.css({fontSize: fontSize + 'px', width:this.min_widget_width, left:this.min_widget_width});
```

---

Other notes:

- You have a typo in:

  ```
  var container,
      grister,      // <<-- Missing 'd' in gridster
      resizeTimer;
  ```
- In `extensions` you have

  ```
  var data = serializedGrid[i];
  this.resize_widget($widget, data.sizex, data.sizey);
  ```

  however a `console.log` of `data` show:

  ```
  data.size_x
  data.size_y
  ```

  not sure how this fits in. The data attribute uses `sizex` / `y` but data property from serialize, (on object), it uses `size_x` / `y` with underscore.

Comment: you are God of jquery and gridster, it's pity that i can't vote. thank so much

Comment: If i can ask, could you find my bug, i copied code from github, some awsome gay wrote shared it, but it works not 100%. When page is resized by mouse drag it works perfect (but some times not). and when i minimize(normal window not maximized) it's resizing function fails at all. Only your fontResizer works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 760px) {
    .gridster .gs-w .item .itemText {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/83MJ6/1/)

Comment: The text is still visible. Also note that grid and cell sizes are dependent on size of window. Bigger window gives bigger grid/cells etc.

Comment: @Morpheus amazing you did it..! and i was about to work with media queries now..!! +1

Comment: Yes. And the text in question is visible at all times. Cell collapsed or not.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, and my previous statement is not correct. It hides when window get's small enough ... but when window is "too wide" the text is always visible.

Comment: In that case change `(max-width: 760px)` to whatever suits you. Let's say `(max-width: 1000px)`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide text by using below type of CSS

```
.gridster .gs-w .item .itemText a.hide-text {
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

now whenever you want to hide text you need to add this class i.e. hide-text on anchor element `<a href="#">Objects</a>` and vice versa to show text remove class

basically you need to try and figure out best possible solution to fit all requirements Good luck

Comment: I think `display:none` is enought, but i do not know how to attach such function on `resize event` of grid